# Nested Category table with Category and SubCategory

Tags: c#, .net, sql, gridview, nested-datalist

I guys,
I have a Category table with CategoryID (primary key), ParentID (int not null) and Category (nvarchar not null).
I´m trying to insert and retrieve in this table Categories with ID CategoryID and SubCategories with ID ParentID.
I´ve been trying the whole week-end with no luck, and hope you can help me. I´m using MSSQL 2008.
The table structure should look like this:

```
-Category1          
        SubCategory1  
        SubCategory2  
    ...  

-Category2  
            SubCategory2  
            SubCategory2  
    ...
```

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: From your comments, seems to me that the problem is more in the UI Control Side (e.g. GridView), how to update your data on gridview row insert and not so much in the database side. If that's the case I think you should clarify that in your question, if it's a technology-specific issue (e.g. WPF, ASP .NET, Windows Forms, etc). By the way, have you seen the example of [RowCommand Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks Adolfo. I´ve researched about rowcommand event and thought it could help. I´ll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I found what I´m looking for here: http://sqllessons.com/categories.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for Common Table Expressions, those allow you to create "recursive-selects".
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1520/recursive-queries-using-common-table-expressions-cte-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks, but the article does not give me what I needed. The scenario is a simple db insert ( works fine), then display the result of Categories (works fine too). Now how to select a Category (CategoryID) and insert a SubCategory (with ID ParentID) underneath. I used Gridview to display the result.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I think I found what I´m looking for here: http://sqllessons.com/categories.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive common table expression:

```
WITH cteTable(madeUpColA, madeUpColB, Etc) as
(
   -- this select statement with the union all is what does the recursive query
   SELECT aCol as madeUpColA, bCol as madeUpColB, Etc
   from dbo.someTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT aCol as madeUpColA, bCol as madeUpColB, Etc
   FROM dbo.someTable st
   INNER JOIN cteTable as c -- inner join on relationship
   ON st.aCol = c.madeUpColA
)
-- this select statement is what retrieves the data from the above query
SELECT madeUpColA, madeUpColB, Etc
FROM cteTable
-- add your other criteria here
```

You can use [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) for the `WITH` statement to specialize your query

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don´t think it should be that complex. I wish I knew a way to select an inserted Category from a gridview or datalist, and based on the ID of that Category insert a SubCategory in the Categories table. I´m sure the magic should happen on the rowcommand of the gridview, but I don´t know how to catch it :(

Comment: Thanks Charles, I think I found what I´m looking for here: http://sqllessons.com/categories.html

Comment: The with statement I posted prevents you from having to worry about the depth of your subcategories. The page you posted, for example, used 3 join statements to get a depth of 4 subcategories. The with statement above does not care if the depth is 1 or many it will still return all of the results

Comment: I could not understand your with statement because my knowledge of sql is at a beginner level. I can see that the one on the page is limited and needs to be adjusted accordingly. Please correct me if anything her is wrong:  WITH cteTable(ColumnA, ColumnB, Etc) as
(
   SELECT aCol as ColumnA, bCol as ColumnB, Etc
   from dbo.someTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT aCol as ColumnA, bCol as ColumnB, Etc
   FROM dbo.someTable st
   INNER JOIN cteTable as c
   ON st.aCol = c.ColumnA
)

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for a simple self join?  If so, this should work:

```
select parent.category, subcat.category as subcategory
from Category subcat join
     Category parent
     on subscat.parentid = parent.categoryid
```

Or do you need to traverse a whole chain of parents?  If so, then the recursive CTE is the better approach.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. I don´t understand your query, but yes it should be a simple joint. And it´s only concerning the table tblCategory: CategoryID [int] Primary key, ParentID[int] NOT NULL, Category [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I think I found what I´m looking for here: http://sqllessons.com/categories.html